# Does crtdbg.h conflict with DirectX?

Tags: c++, directx, crtdbg.h

I just discovered the hidden gem `crtdbg.h` which makes memory leak detection so much easier. Unfortunately, when I linked DirectX into my program today, I got some errors I've never seen before.

```
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.h(425): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.h(425): error C2091: function returns function
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.h(425): error C2802: static member 'operator new' has no formal parameters
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.h(426): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.h(426): error C2090: function returns array
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.inl(1003): error C2761: 'void *(__cdecl *_D3DXMATRIXA16::operator new(void))(size_t)' : member function redeclaration not allowed
1>e:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3dx10math.inl(1003): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

It seems like when crtdbg overrides the new operator, it breaks something in the DirectX SDK (in case you didn't notice in the errors, I am using the DirectX 11 SDK). Is anything like this documented? A few searches didn't yield any results. I really hope I can continue to use these memory debugging tools, and any workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No repro.  Use the C/C++, Preprocessor, Generate Preprocessed File option.  Open the generated .i file, find _D3DXMATRIXA16 back and post what you see.  And document version numbers.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see that option, the closest thing I can see is "Preprocess to a File", but it tells me it can't find "base.obj", which is my base.h/base.cpp file. I solved it, however.

Comment: That's a linker error.  Hard to help you.

Comment: @HansPassant Its ok, I fixed it. I don't know where the linker error came from, other than the fact that it only happened when I used that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I found [this post via Google.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057248/953613) (I wish Stack Overflow had shown it to me on the sidebar when I was typing this! Or maybe it did and I missed it...).

Basically, I need to move the including of `crtdbg.h`, `stdlib.h` and the definition of `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` to a separate header, and use the `Forced Include File` option under **C/C++** >> **Advanced** in the project properties page to force that include file everywhere. This seems to make it override all other `new` overrides.